# itextsharp change table cell data

Tags: c#, itext

i have a pdf file 
i want to change a table cell data by itextsharp 
is there any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created pdf form to implement the same thing.

you can find [reference & source code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FillFormFieldsOfPDFs.aspx?msg=2409548) here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to modify an existing PDF using iTextSharp, but when I had a requirement like that in the past I used [Adobe's FDF (Form Data Format) Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html) to open an existing PDF document and set values for form fields within the document.  The end result was a dynamically populated PDF with a highly polished appearance.  Unfortunately, the data only saves if the end user has the full acrobat - otherwise they can only print it.